# Junit Test Case for Apache camel service

Tags: java, sql, rest, junit, apache-camel

I created apache camel rest service to query data from DB

```
.get("/{id}/CodeId").description("get the CodeId").outType(String.class)
                .id("CodeId").param().name("codeid").type(RestParamType.path).description("Getting Id")
                .dataType("string").endParam().route()
                .to("sql:select * from table1 where C_ID=:#${header.codeid} ")
                .process(new Processor() {

                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
                        String JId = null;
                        try {
                            List<HashMap> version = (List<HashMap>) ex.getIn().getBody();
                            if (version != null && version.size() > 0) {
                                LOG.debug(
                                        "jId------------------------------>" + version.get(0).get("J_ID"));
                                JId = (String) version.get(0).get("J_ID");
                            }

                            ex.getIn().setBody(JId, String.class);
                            ex.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 201);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).endRest();
```

Actually it works fine but i was not able to write junit test cases for the service.

Can anyone please suggest me a method to write a Junit Test Case to check the values from the service ??

Comment: Did you read documentation https://camel.apache.org/testing.html ?

Comment: yes i read the document but was not able to get the right method

Comment: One thing you could do is place all the pipe logic into a "direct:" sub-route and test this sub-route using the standard testing support from camel.

Comment: @rparree can you show me an example as  i am  new to camel

Comment: Or just use any http client (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any http client (for example camel-http)

```
class RestDemoTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  override def createRouteBuilder(): RouteBuilder = new RestDslRoutes()

  @Test
  def smokeTest(): Unit ={
    val body: String = template.requestBodyAndHeader("http://localhost:9898/demo/status","",Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET", classOf[String])
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(body,Is.is("Running"))
  }

}
```

Sample code is in scala, but i'm sure you get the idea

EDIT: as per request a sample with obtaining a mock:

```
class RestDemoTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  override def createRouteBuilder(): RouteBuilder = new RestDslRoutes()

  // This example uses auto mocking endpoints based on a pattern
  override def isMockEndpointsAndSkip: String = "sql:*"

  @Test
  def mockDemo(): Unit = {
    // Obtain auto-created mock endpoint (false indicates: don't create if it does not exist yet. Helps with typos
    val mockEndpoint: MockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:sql:update foo set bar=10",false)
    // Set expectations/behaviour etc
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1)

    val body: String = template.requestBody("http://localhost:9898/demo/update", "",  classOf[String])

    /// assert expectations/behaviour 
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()
  }
```

Comment: You might want to mark it as the answer in that case. Thanks

Comment: if i use the above code in junit for a update service, it will update the table since, it is calling the backend . do u have any ideas to test the update service.??

Comment: You will have to use a mock for a unit test (or a different database for an integration test). For mocking: override isMockEndpointsAndSkip and use getMockEndpoint inside your test-case. Alternatively you could use an "Advice", but i think you can just use a mock in this case.

Comment: can you show me an example for the above service in mock??

Answer (score 1):

In fact I have documented everything around unit test cases here :

http://bushorn.com/unit-testing-apache-camel/

http://bushorn.com/camel-unit-testing-using-mock-endpoint/

In your scenario, what you have to do is, you have to replace whatever rest from endpoint in your route with a direct endpoint. That way you can send any payload from your unit test case. Its always a good practice to do these unit test cases protocol agnostic. Meaning, dont involve REST, JMS, STOMP or any external calls in your unit cases, that way you can focus to test only your routing logic. Protocol level testing you can anyway cover in integration testing.

Cheers.